# What's the official Microsoft way to track counts of dynamic controls to be reconstructed upon Postback?

Tags: asp.net, controls, postback, viewstate

When creating dynamic controls based on a data source of arbitrary and changing size, what is the official way **to track exactly how many controls need to be rebuilt** into the page's control collection after a Postback operation (i.e. on the server side during the ASP.NET page event lifecycle) specifically the point at which dynamic controls are supposed to be rebuilt?  Where is the arity stored for retrieval and reconstruction usage?

By "official" I mean the Microsoft way of doing it. There exist hacks like Session storage, etc but I want to know the bonafide or at least Microsoft-recommended way.  I've been unable to find a documentation page stating this information. Usually code samples work with a set of dynamic controls of known numbers. It's as if doing otherwise would be tougher.

**Update**: I'm not inquiring about user controls or static expression of declarative controls, but instead about dynamically injecting controls completely from code-behind, whether they be mine, 3rd-party or built-in ASP.NET controls.

Comment: `ViewState` holds control data, not rendered content... So if data is present it will be correctly rendered by item template definition of a repeater control. What you define in repeater item templates is therefore irrelevant.

Comment: Your question is poorly phrased to the actual problem you're having. Dynamic is not what you think and refer to in this question of yours. If a repeater is defined in an ASPX page it's static control no matter how you define its item templates. They're all static. Dynamic ones are those that are created in code and added to the page's controls collection and don't exists in the ASPX at all. Even `OnItemDataBound` created controls are *usually* considered static, since they're related to control rendering.

Comment: Thanks. You're right. I modified the question by removing the mixture of the two. Repeater and related are gone and replaced with pure dynamic intention.

Comment: My answer still stands rephrased question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This greatly depends on the problem at hand, and the type of controls you're recreating. Are they all simple text boxes or various different complex custom user controls. the main thing here is: **if you want your dynamic control to regain state after a post-back, you have to re-create it in the Init phase of a page life-cycle.**

Anyway. There's nothing like a *Microsoft way* or *Microsoft recommended way* basically. When you're dynamically adding several simple controls of the same type a hidden field with a count would do the trick, but when you have several complex controls other ways would have to be used. You could still hidden fields and save control's full type strings in them (ie. System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox) and re-instantiate them. But think of an even more complex example of putting various controls on different parts in the page... And initializing them to a specific state. That would be a bit more challenging. Hence no Microsoft way... The recommended way is to recreate in Init phase. And that's it.

Everything can be solved, but sometimes one took a wrong direction in the UI and things could be done easier using a different approach.

### Additional explanation

This state-full technique of `ViewState` that Asp.net uses is considered the worse culprit with web developers in general. That's why Asp.net MVC developers think the new framework is bliss since its much more suited to the state-less HTTP protocol. Me being one of them. :D

Comment: You're suggesting Microsoft wouldn't have a standard way of their own in advanced shipped WebControls  (like in Repeater, DataList, GridView, etc) to rebuild control state upon Postback? I consider those controls quite complex having templates and nested controls.  Looking for the ways Microsoft tracks the counts of those things which are dynamically built and managed by Microsoft.

Comment: @John K: Control state is a completely different story. It's out-of-the-box working *thing* that makes **static** page controls to regain their previous state that makes it possible to track *change* events and provide repopulating controls with data (in repeaters for example). But as I understood your question you were after a technique of **dynamic** page controls and not **static** ones. Asp.net doesn't have a built-in functionality to auto-recreate dynamic controls provided they have state in view state. You have to take care of it yourself.

Comment: I think I'm trying to get a bit closer to that in my own implementation and thus the question.  I guess another way to ask might have been: are the same mechanisms available to me as Microsoft used when building their shipped controls? Often in .NET same mechanisms are available to developers as Microsoft used - I think ASP.NET is at a high enough abstraction layer to afford that to us, but sometimes Microsoft has used specialized mechanisms that are not available at our abstraction level although we're attempting similar things.

Comment: **Exactly the same** mechanisms can be used by custom control developers as Microsoft uses in theirs as long as these developers know exactly how Microsoft did it. :) .Net Reflector may help lots.

Comment: I don't mean user controls - I'll update the question with that info. Thanks for pointing out the clarification.

Comment: So back to static vs dynamic, what we consider static built-in ASP.NET controls are actually dynamic controls to Microsoft who programmed them, am I incorrect?  In that case I assume the ways Microsoft used to reconstruct dynamic control counts can also be leveraged by myself, but only if I find out about them.

Comment: Maybe a better thing would be to explain the exact problem you're having with a repeater. `EnableViewState` usually does the trick just fine.

Comment: **Static controls** are those that are defined directly in the ASPX page hence they directly exist as properties of the `Page` class... **Dynamic controls** are those that are created in code and put in the page programatically (into some place holder probably) and don't exist anywhere in the Page class so they can't be re-created because their reference property doesn't exist anywhere.

Comment: I see what you mean. In that case I'm only talking about dynamic controls and recreating them upon postback. You've given me something to ponder which I will do before returning to this question, and you have provided an answer to it in your initial response. I'm just understanding through our conversation how to splice what you mean from my intention and the differences.

Comment: The thing is that **every** control you add to an ASPX file, becomes a property of a custom `Page` class whose instance is used in page life-cycle process. ASPX is only used in the rendering phase. Hence these controls are accessible directly from the code. When you add dynamic controls and place them in some place holder (probably static) only then those controls are complete aliens to page. Their state can't be auto-managed. You have to recreate them in the **INIT** phase of the page life-cycle otherwise they'll loose state. But have in mind they need to have exactly the same ID as before.

Comment: Indeed the same ID I understand because I once tried dynamic control programming  without setting it properly :) That's one royal PITA mistake that's not soon forgotten! Incidentally in the past I've set dynamic control counts into the user Session but really don't like to do that. It was more of a quick solution at the time so I doubt it was actually the best.   The init phase I understand too but  tracking of counts seems obscure, evasive to me, like the prodigal son who has yet to arrive home. :)

Comment: +1 Thanks. You certainly earned that point many times over. I'm going to go with your suggestion of tracking the count and such meta data in a hidden field of the page. Then what I need for init will be available in the Request collection for use even before ViewState comes online.

Comment: @John K: Exactly. And store just as much info in the hidden field as needed. No more. Sometimes a number will do. sometimes more data will have to be added. And thanks for all the points I got from you.

Comment: I want to apply a moniker as I plan to reuse this concept in future projects and am strongly considering naming my hidden input field "__PissPoorState" because all things considered it's a bit like that. However it doesn't withstand the view-source test so maybe I'll just have to go for a more generic __CustomState.

Comment: @John K: You could as well go with `__DynamicState`